# get only first N element of large xml object

Tags: php, xml, performance, curl, optimization

I am integrating an third party API which return about 20MB of data for each search. It returns about 500 items. This is a too much data for me. So, I want to just use first 50 items.

My attempt:

```
$xml    = simplexml_load_string($apiRequest);
$object = json_decode(json_encode($xml));
$items  = array_slice($object, 0, 50);
```

Approximate response time from the API is around 50 Seconds (when I tested on postman). After response received, converting it to std object and doing other calculation slow down a lot. So, I want to speed up. I want to split the XML response received getting first 50 items and then convert it into std object. Is there any way to do it? Other suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: The most APIs let you add a parameter to limit the number of results, so you could not only improve the time to convert but also the time to receive.

Comment: Do avoid serializing it to JSON and read the XML directly. Try using the XMLReader class. It is the current standard API for that large files.

Comment: I have communicate with my provider @lukegv, I cannot limit the number of results. So, I am facing issue

Answer (score -1):

If I were to parse such a huge XML response, I would do it using a stream parser.

I don't have an experience with one, but a quick google search points to https://github.com/prewk/xml-string-streamer.

Give it a shot and if you have specific issues then we can try to solve that one.

Comment: Thanks for the link @avk dai